# How to test if a URL contains certain parameters but not others using regex

Tags: java, android, regex

I have an url in this format:

http://www.example.com/path?param1=value1&param2=value2

I need a regex to match the path and params1 and params2 in any order but if param3 is present then I need it to fail so:

```
String str1 = "/path?param1=value1&param2=value2"; // This will match
String str2 = "/path?param2=value2&param1=value1"; // This will match
String str3 = "/path?param1=value1&param2=value&param3=value3"; // This will not match
```

So for I've tried using lookarounds to match the parameters but it is failing:

```
/path\?(?!param3)(?=param1=.*)(?=param2=.*)
```

Any thoughts?

P.D. For the curious I'm trying to match a specific URL from an AndroidManifest.xml file https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html

Comment: Can you just count the number of &'s in the string and if it is more than 1 then you can assume there are more than 2 parameters? You could skip the regex altogether then.

Comment: I need to use regex since it is the only rule that I can apply to filter through the data element https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html

Comment: Can't do something like `if (StringUtils.countOccurrencesOf(url, "&") > 1)` ?

Comment: @blahfunk thanks for taking the time to answer, but my regex is going to be added on an XML file, so I can't use code. Specifically inside the AndroidManifest.xml on the data element in the android:pathPattern="string" attribute

Comment: Figured I'd try, though I figured you knew you couldn't use it already. Sometimes we end up so zoned in on one solution that we miss simple others, so I wanted to give the code just in case... Sorry mate :/

Comment: No worries! thanks! @blahfunk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one out:

```
^(?!.*param3)(?=.*param1=)(?=.*param2=).*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/rI1lH5/1

If you want the path in as well, then

```
^\/path(?!.*param3)(?=.*param1=)(?=.*param2=).*$
```

Answer (score 0):

This started as a comment and I got a little carried away. You can sanitize the query and see if it matches the parameters you need it to and avoid regex all together (if possible)

```
private boolean checkProperQueryString(String url, String[] requiredKeys){
    try{
        UrlQuerySanitizer sanitizer = new UrlQuerySanitizer(url);

        // Check that you have the right number of parameters
        List<UrlQuerySanitizer.ParameterValuePair> parameters =
               sanitizer.getParameterList();
        if(parameters == null || parameters.size() != requiredKeys.length)
            return false;

        // Check to make sure that the parameters you have are the
        // correct ones
        for(String key : requiredKeys){
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(sanitizer(getValue(key))
                return false;
        }

        // We pass every test, success!
        return true;   
    } catch(Exception e){
        // Catch any errors (haven't tested this so not sure of errors)
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can then make the call doing something like this

```
boolean validUrl = checkProperQueryString(url, new String[]{"param1", "param2"});
```

**This doesn't directly answer your question, again just too much for a comment :P**

Let me know if this just adds confusion for anyone and I can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

The regex provided by Michael works well but there is a glitch. It also evaluates newParam. So we should change that with:

```
^(?!.*(\\?|&)param3)(?=.*(\\?|&)param1=)(?=.*(\\?|&)param2=).*$
```

Basically we check if the parameter name starts with a ? or &. Also if you want to make a parameter optional then you can just put a ? at the end like:

```
(?!.*(\\?|&)param3)(?=.*(\\?|&)param1=)(?=.*(\\?|&)param2=)?.*$
```

In the above param2 is optional.